# Find $k,t\in \mathbb R$ such that $B^{-1}=kB+tI$ where $B=A^4-2A^3-A-5I$ and $A$ is a $2\times 2$ reflection matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Find $k,t\in \mathbb R$ such that $B^{-1}=kB+tI$ where $B=A^4-2A^3-A-5I$ and $A$ is a $2\times 2$ reflection matrix.

I found out that :
$B=A^4-2A^3-A-5I \implies B= (A^2)^2 - (2A^2)A - A - 5I \implies B= I-2IA-A-5I \implies B=I-3A-5I \implies B=-3A-4I $

I'm not sure how to continue. I tried to take the inverse of $B$ but I get :

$B^{-1} = (-3A-4I)^{-1}$

Which I'm not sure if can be solved and how. So I guess I took the wrong way.

Can please someone give me an hint how to find these $k,t \in \mathbb R$?

**Note - $A^2 = I$**

Comment: Does it mean, $A^2=A$ ? Then $B=-2A-5I$.

Comment: Yes $A^2=A$. But why $B=-2A-5I$?

Comment: Because $A^n=A$, so $B=A-2A-A-5I=-2A-5I$.

Comment: No! I'm sorry! $A^2=I$

Comment: If you required $A^2 = I$, then projection onto the $x$-axis would not be a projection; I'm pretty sure you mean $A^2 = A$.

Comment: It's projection on a line. As far as I know it should satisfies $A^2=I$.

Comment: @JohnHughes You are correct. I'm sorry ! I meant reflection matrix.

Comment: The you should edit, so that we know exactly what you want, i.e., that $A^2=I$, no matter how the name is.

Answer (score 1):

$$
B = A^4 - 2 A^3 -A - 5I\\
= (A^2)^2 - 2 A A^2 -A - 5I\\
= (A)^2 - 2 A A -A - 5I\\
= A^2 - 2 A^2 -A - 5I\\
= -A^2  -A - 5I\\
= -A  -A - 5I\\
= -2A  - 5I
$$
through repeated application of $A^2 = A$.

To find $B^{-1}$, try multiplying out
$$
I = B B^{-1} = (-2A + 5I) \cdot (kB + tI)
$$
and setting it equal to $I$ and solving for $k$ and $t$. Substitute in the formula for $B$ in terms of $A$ to get an equality involving only $A$ and $I$ (after replacing $A^2$ with $A$ throughout), and it should be pretty straightforward.

Comment: But if $A$ is $2\times 2$ projection matrix then $A^2=I$ and not $A$. Isn't it correct?

Comment: Also notice I was looking for $B^{-1}$. How can I derive it from this solution?

Comment: No, that's not correct; if that were the definition, then projection to the $x$-axis, given by $A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$, would not be a projection, and that's just crazy.

Comment: I'm so sorry.. I meant reflection! sorry very much!

Comment: I'm really sorry for giving you the wrong information.

Comment: Fixed. Thanks Dietrich.

Comment: John I'm not sure you noticed it but I meant reflection matrix. Why is it straightforward? I have only one equation for two variables. Isn't it correct?

Comment: Syndicator: see if you can work with something analogous to what I've said, but for reflections. I've done my part. :)

Comment: Thank you. Actually I don't care about the first step much as the second one. How do I solve for $k,t$ with only one equation?